# what is the problem with my THE NEXT PALLINDROME solution

Tags: c

this is a solution of SPOJ's next pallindrome. the logic gives right solution in other ide but is rejected by the SPOJ.
what is the problem with this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int pallin(int i){
    int oint=i;
    int re,rev=0;
    while(oint!=0){
        re=oint%10;
        rev=rev*10+re;
        oint/=10;
    }
    if(rev==i){
        return rev;
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }

}
int main(){
    int i,num;
    scanf("%d",&i);
    while(i--){
        scanf("%d",&num);
        for(int n=num+1;n<100000;++n){
            if(pallin(n)) {
                printf("%d\n",pallin(n));
            break;

            }
            else{
                continue;
            }

        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [chuckles] The [SPOJ question](https://www.spoj.com/problems/PALIN/) says... *"For a given positive integer K of not more than **1000000** digits"* so this is a string not a number exercise ;)

Comment: i have added 10^6. still wrong answer coming.is that your point??!

Comment: No, `int` will not hold a **million digit number**. A 32-bit `int` will only hold a **nine digit number**.

Comment: On all major platforms `int` is a signed 32-bit number which can hold values from little under minus two billion to little over plus two billion. That's nine digits (minus sign not included). Even `unsigned long long` which is a 64-bit number and can hold *much* larger numbers will be able to handle numbers with millions of digits. Instead treat your input as *strings* and use a string algorithm.